# c++ constexpr pointer and constexpr comparison

Tags: c++, constexpr

In the following code:

```cpp
struct test{
    struct Data{};

    static constexpr const Data data1{};
    static constexpr const Data data2{};

    static constexpr const Data* pdata1 = &data1;
    static constexpr const Data* pdata2 = &data2;

    static constexpr const bool b1 = pdata1 == pdata2; // OK
    static constexpr const bool b2 = pdata1 != pdata2; // OK
    static constexpr const bool b3 = pdata1 <  pdata2; // ERROR: is not a constant expression
};
```

Compiler allow me to compare pointers with `==` and `!=`. But `<`, `>` cause compiler error.
Why so?

Comment: its no legalese but whether those 2 pointers point to the same object can be determined at compile time, but their respective address would be a runtime property hence why you cant constexpr evaluate it

Comment: @Borgleader why address ordering must be runtime property? All static values stored at fixed memory segment.

Comment: @tower120 - But is it always in the same relation to each other? There's no guarantee of that. And so it's not a constant expression that may be known before the fact.

Comment: Even `std::less<>{}(pdata1, pdata2)` is not constant expression.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I wonder, how they can actually change relation to each other? If static data compiled into solid binary. Or you meant across different compilers?

Comment: @tower120 - Different compilers, or even different invocations of the same compiler. A constant expression is not just a value which cannot change, it's a value that's guaranteed to be uniquely determined under the C++ specification for a program's translation.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Not that clear, OP's `pdata1` or `sizeof(int)` might have different values.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Their actual value is not material. What's material is that it's constant even in the abstract machine. The result of the comparison isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing the addresses of two unrelated objects has an unspecified result

> **[expr.rel]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.rel#3) Comparing unequal pointers to objects is defined as follows:
>
> - If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher
>     subscript compares greater.
> - If two pointers point to different non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects of such members, recursively, the
>     pointer to the later declared member compares greater provided the two
>     members have the same access control and provided their class is not a
>     union.
> - Otherwise, neither pointer compares greater than the other.
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.rel#4) If two operands p and q compare equal, `p<=q` and `p>=q` both yield
>   true and `p<q` and `p>q` both yield false. Otherwise, if a pointer p
>   compares greater than a pointer q, `p>=q`, `p>q`, `q<=p`, and `q<p` all yield
>   true and `p<=q`, `p<q`, `q>=p`, and `q>p` all yield false. Otherwise, the
>   result of each of the operators is unspecified.

And a relational expression with an unspecified result is explicitly forbidden from appearing in a constant expression

> **[expr.const]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2) An expression e is a core constant expression unless the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would
>   evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - ...
> - a relational or equality operator where the result is unspecified; or
> - ...

A compiler is required to issue a diagnostic when it encounters something forbidden in the evaluation of a constant expression. Hence you get an error.

Always bear in mind that the C++ standard defines things in terms of an abstract machine. Constant expressions are those which have well-defined semantics in that abstract machine, and so may be evaluated "at compile time" when all arguments are known. If something is unspecified in the abstract machine, it cannot produce a well-defined constant expression, so it's prohibited.

Comment: So.... Even comparing static pointers to static objects is illegal? Like this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3cbc8f5c5817f2b

Comment: @tower120 - Unspecified. And your modified example uses regular const objects. Since it doesn't have to be a constant expression in the abstract machine, it's now perfectly valid.